# 日本語英語まじりのテキスト画像からテキスト文字列を取り出したい

Tags: 画像認識

たくさんあるゲーム画面のスクショの
特定の位置にある文字列を抜き出したいです

---

https://myafu-python.com/work/text-extraction/
こちらの手順に従って画像パス以外同じコードを
以下の画像に対して実行したところ

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

えおABCabc123

という途中からの文字列しか取得できませんでした
これは使い方の問題なのか純粋に精度の問題なんでしょうか

出力される文字の　色　背景色　フォント　フォントサイズ
とかは調べればわかる状態なんですが
それでも完全な文字列取得は難しいのでしょうか

---

目的が達成できれば言語もAPIも問わないので
実現方法があれば教えていただけるとうれしいです

Comment: 文字列の先頭が欠けているようなので、主に先頭部分(あるいは上下左右全部)に余白を継ぎ足してから認識処理を行ってみてはどうでしょう？ 例えば1次元バーコードだと前後にクワイエットゾーンという空白領域が必要ですので、それの類推です。

Comment: 参考にしている記事では segmentation mode を 6(Assume a single uniform block of text)にしていますが、それを、7(Treat the image as a single text line) にすると全ての文字を読み取ることができるかもしれません。ちなみに、コマンドラインで tessract を実行してみると問題なく読み取っています。`tesseract -l jpn --psm 7 U67lD.png stdout`